# Using cURL to get all links in a website (not only the page)

Tags: php, curl, hyperlink

I use the following PHP script to get all the links on a given page, but I'm trying to get all the links on a website as a whole.

```
<?php

    function urlLooper($url){

        $urlArray = array();

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        $regex='|<a.*?href="(.*?)"|';
        preg_match_all($regex,$result,$parts);
        $links=$parts[1];
        foreach($links as $link){
            array_push($urlArray, $link);
        }
        curl_close($ch);

        foreach($urlArray as $value){
            echo $value . '<br />';
        }
    }

    $url = 'http://www.justfundraising.com/';
    urlLooper($url);
```

?>

Is there any way to use cURL (or any other method frankly) to get all the links on a website? I have access to the server in case you're wondering.

My idea was to generate all the links from, say, the homepage and then pass those links back through the same function to get a new list of links ignoring any duplicates. I figure that way I'll get all the pages.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You could investigate `phpQuery` which eases page retrieval and parsing, allowing to build a simple spider less cumbersome than with manual curl and text extraction approaches.

Comment: Your script above just helped me immensely, thankyou =)

Comment: I used [this](http://blog.viktorkelemen.com/2011/07/get-links-from-page-with-bash.html); not sure if it would help.

Answer (score 3):

As @mario mentions above perhaps look into using phpQuery (http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/). Once you have downloaded the library and included it on your page, below is some example code showing how you can get an array that contains all the links from the string you pass to it (I have just hardcoded a string in the newDocument function as an example):

```
$links = phpQuery::newDocument('<a href="test1.html">Test 1</a><a href="test2.html">Test 2</a><a href="test3.html">Test 3</a>')->find('a');
$array_links = array();
foreach($links as $r) {
    $array_links[] = pq($r)->attr('href');
}
die("<pre>".print_r($array_links,true)."</pre>");
```

The above code will return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => test1.html
    [1] => test2.html
    [2] => test3.html
)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

curl only fetches what you tell it to. It won't parse the contents for you, and it won't recursively fetch "external" resources referred to by the content. You'll have to rummage around in the returned HTML yourself, parse out image/script links, and use more curl calls to fetch those.

In other words, you'll have to replicate `wget`, which boils down to: just use [wget](http://www.gnu.org/s/wget/).

Answer (score 1):

i was trying the same using simplehtmldom . but the code crashed after some time . actually i was trying to use dfs method here which can overflow the stack at one point .

you can check this method using cURL

here is my code :

```
<?php
traverse($home,0);

function traverse($url,$depth)
{
if($depth>1)return;
$html = file_get_html($url);
foreach($html->find('a') as $element)
{
    $nurl = $element->href;
    echo $nurl."<br>";
    traverse($nurl,$depth+1);

}
}
?>
```