# Reading URL's and parse information

Tags: php

I have a txt file with 5000 lines with URL's. WHat i'm trying to do is to open every url to extract every url (that first url have).
My problem is, the first line the script opens the URL and tell me how many links i have with no problem. But for the rest of the URL's in the file isnt showing anything...the array show something like this:

```
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
```

My code:

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('***mytxt file****');

$pathComponents = explode(",", trim($homepage)); //line breaker

//echo "<pre>";print_r($pathComponents);echo "</pre>";

$count_nlines = count($pathComponents);

for ($i=0;$i<3;$i++) {

$request_url = $pathComponents[$i];
//echo $request_url . "<br>";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);    // The url to get links from
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // We want to get the respone
$result = curl_exec($ch);

$regex='|<a.*?href="(.*?)"|';
preg_match_all($regex,$result,$parts);
$links=$parts[1];

echo "<pre>";print_r($links);echo "</pre>";

curl_close($ch);
}
```

Any ideas?!

Comment: Do you have an example of your array file?

Comment: You mean the first array i receive?

Comment: No your array in your .txt file.

Comment: http://www.laredoute.pt/t-shirt-franzida-especial-amamentacao/prod-17000008-512773.aspx,
http://www.laredoute.pt/top-especial-amamentacao/prod-17003124-512773.aspx,
http://www.laredoute.pt/t-shirt-especial-amamentacao/prod-17003147-512773.aspx, ***etc

Comment: I deleted my other comments. If you're interested, I have a working script that could be of use to you, and I could post it as an answer. I couldn't figure out how to fix your present problem.

Comment: If you can do that, i really appreciate

Comment: Ok, and let me know if it works for you in a comment in the script and if not, I will delete the answer afterwards.

Comment: Answer posted. Let me know if it works out.

Comment: How are you making out with my code, any luck?

Comment: i couldnt test it yeat. but later i will let u know ;)

Comment: @Fred Your script doesnt match what i need. thanks anyway :)

Comment: ok then. Not a problem, cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're looping through the wrong thing.  Try changing this:

```
for ($i=0;$i<3;$i++) {
```

To this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($pathComponents); $i++)
```

Comment: @subversive Sorry, I can't test your code since I don't have PHP on this computer (my work computer).  I do C# at work (PHP is on my home computer).  Hopefully, Fred will be able to give you some code.  If not, here is another option to accomplish what you are trying to do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031058/using-curl-to-get-all-links-in-a-website-not-only-the-page and http://www.jaygilford.com/php/common-questions/how-to-get-all-links-from-a-web-page/ and http://www.qualitycodes.com/tip/27/using-curl-to-get-all-links-in-a-webpage.html